# CSV reading issue

Tags: php, csv

I have a CSV file (comma delimited) but I have also some commas in my data because of which I am having trouble ready CSV.Is there any way I can user comma in my data and also as delimiter?

Comment: I can't use Tab delimited file because of spaces in data

Comment: `"data","somedata with coma, blabal","other data"` - and so on and so on

Comment: as @nospor said, surround your column values with quotation marks `"value, with, comma" , "next value"`

Comment: basically i am exporting data source from other database where data is already stored and i am unable to edit that data before importing to my local database

Comment: If your export is correct, it should be embraced with with quotes. Othervise, it is non parseable and non importable and you will have to fix it manually.